# How to apply if else in html using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code

```
<span data-ng-repeat="s in d.sInfo track by $index" title="{{ s.sFirstName }} {{ s.sLastname }}">

<strong>{{ s.sFirstName }} {{ s.sLastname }}</strong> ({{ s.permission }})<br>

</span>
```

What i want is that if login user and shared user are same then i will show "YOU"

i am trying something like this ,

```
<strong>{{ s.sFirstName }} {{ s.sLastname }} || s.name == s.FirstName s.Lastname |"YOU"</strong> ({{ s.permission }})
```

I can do a loop in controller .But is there any way to achieve this in view itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look nice (in this case), but it might prove useful in other situation (with more compact expressions): You can use a ternary operator `(cond) ? expr : expr`

```
<strong>{{
    ((u.firstname===user.firstname)&&(u.lastname===user.lastname))?
            'YOU':
            u.firstname+' '+u.lastname}}
</strong>
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/cfgfL/)**.

---

**NOTE**

The other approaches mentioned (e.g. using `ngShow`, `ngIf` etc) are viable solutions, but they involve the creation/destruction/manipulation of additional DOM elements, which might have a noticable impact on performance if the `users` list grows big.

BTW, you could also use `ngSwitch` to the same end.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `ng-if` directive for that

```
<strong ng-if="!yourConditionHere">{{ s.sFirstName }} {{ s.sLastname }}</strong>
<strong ng-if="yourConditionHere">YOU</strong>
```

Replace `yourConditionHere` with your condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-if` or `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directives or `scope` function

**Using ng-if directive**'

```
  <strong ng-if="s.FirstName"> {{ s.sFirstName }} {{ s.sLastname }} </strong>
  <strong ng-if="!s.FirstName"> You </strong>
```

**Using ng-show directive**'

```
  <strong ng-show="s.FirstName"> {{ s.sFirstName }} {{ s.sLastname }} </strong>
  <strong ng-show="!s.FirstName"> You </strong>
```

**Using ng-hide directive**'

```
  <strong ng-hide="!s.FirstName"> {{ s.sFirstName }} {{ s.sLastname }} </strong>
  <strong ng-hide="s.FirstName"> You </strong>
```

**Using Scope function**

In your case, you can also use `scope` function to get the name

```
  <strong> {{getName(s)}} </strong>


  $scope.getName = function (s) {
     if (s.FirstName) return s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName;
     return 'You';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-if works just fine.

You can also set up a filter that returns the user display name, to avoid putting logic in your markup

I am setting up a jsfiddle to show you an example.

Edit:

There you go

http://jsfiddle.net/jN3Pt/1

```
angular.filter('userDisplayName', function(loggedInUser) {
  return function(user) {
    if ( loggedInUser.firstName === user.firstName ) return "YOU";
    return user.firstName
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) ?

```
<strong ng-show="truthy_condition"></strong>
```